# Leaflet : Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined)

Tags: angular, leaflet

l am trying to get objects keys from JSON API url , content on latitude and longitude from server . The data json api content on Object keys and those keys are change all time . l want to get only the coordinates inside of those Object keys and add it to leaflet map marker as array then show on map . But the problem is i have `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined)`

```
  //coords
  points: Array<any> = [];

  // short data json
   data =[
{

  "22a7f183": [
    "502F0C",
    56.9227,
    23.9790,
    16,
    0,
    0,
    "0000",
    "T-EVRA43",
    "",
    "",
    1573389319,
    "RIX",
    "",
    "",
    1,
    0,
    "GPSMONT",
    0,
    ""
  ],
}]

  MarkerMap() {      

      this.points = Object.keys(this.data)
      .map(key => this.data[key])
      .map((position) => ({
        lat: position[1],
        lng: position[2]
      }));
      this.points.forEach((point) => {

        L.marker([point.lat,point.lng]).addTo(globalMap)
        .bindPopup('Ionic 4 <br> Leaflet.')
        .openPopup();
        console.log(point.lat,point.lng)


      });
    }
```

Also how can i avoid empty objects insides array ?

[Live Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angularssas)

Answer (score 1):

What is your data source? Maybe, some records don't have coordinates? Did you validate that?

If you have incomplete elements in the array, you can filter the array using the `filter` method:

```
this.points = Object.keys(this.data)
  .map(key => this.data[key])
  .map((position) => ({
    lat: position[1],
    lng: position[2]
  }))
  .filter(position => position.lat && position.lng);
```

Additionally, you should check your coordinates are numbers.

Comment: Thank you for replying . After i did `filter(position => position.lat && position.lng)` i got nothing in console log . but if i deleted i got `lat: undefined`
`lng: undefined`

Comment: you can check out on [https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angularssas]